# How to get "their" changes in the middle of conflicting Git rebase?

Tags: git, rebase, git-rebase

I have conflicting branches, `feature_x` branched from `main`.

Let's say when rebasing `feature_x` on current `main`, while resolving conflicts, I decide to take **some** (not all) of "their" (i.e. `main`) files as-is.
How do I do that?

I tried:

```sh
git checkout main:foo/bar.java
fatal: reference is not a tree: TS-modules-tmp:foo/bar.java
  
git checkout refs/heads/main:foo/bar.java
fatal: reference is not a tree: refs/heads/TS-modules-tmp:foo/bar.java
```

Comment: Note: if you're rebasing branch2 onto branch1, the replaying happens relative to branch1, so "theirs" is actually branch2 and "ours" is branch1.  http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Counter-intuitive-results-for-git-show-and-git-checkout-during-rebase-with-conflict-td2370354.html

Comment: See also https://github.com/git/git/commit/f30301657b68561392d910f6196380dd3976549e

Comment: This just cost me about 20 hours of diligent work. I honestly thought "ours" would always be the working copy.

Comment: @TheodoreR.Smith `git reflog` to find your lost work and `git checkout $hash` to get it back right away before it's gone for good.

Answer (score 646, accepted):

You want to use:

```
git checkout --ours foo/bar.java
git add foo/bar.java
```

If you rebase a branch `feature_x` against `main` (i.e. running `git rebase main` while on branch `feature_x`), during rebasing `ours` refers to `main` and `theirs` to `feature_x`.

As pointed out in the [git-rebase docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase):

> Note that a rebase merge works by replaying each commit from the
> working branch on top of the  branch. Because of this, when
> a merge conflict happens, the side reported as ours is the so-far
> rebased series, starting with <upstream>, and theirs is the working
> branch. In other words, the sides are swapped.

For further details [read this thread](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Counter-intuitive-results-for-git-show-and-git-checkout-during-rebase-with-conflict-td2370354.html).

Comment: I'm sure there's a good reason why merge and rebase have opposite meaning for "ours" and "theirs", but consistency would have been so much better.

Comment: So `their` in OPs question corresponds to `--ours` in the actual command.

Comment: Note that `--ours` also corresponds (more intuitively) to the 'Current Changes' in your IDE when resolving conflicts, whereas `--theirs` corresponds to 'Incoming Changes'

Comment: @ut9081 in your /VScode/ IDE ;)

Comment: @laurent It's because if you rebase a branch `feature` off of branch `master`, then the mechanics are that it starts back at master, then cherry-picks each change up to the head of feature, resolving conflicts at each commit.  That is why it's the other way around.  We are starting on master, and cherry-picking "their" changes.

Answer (score 9):

If you want to pull a particular file from another branch just do

```
git checkout branch1 -- filenamefoo.txt
```

This will pull a version of the file from one branch into the current tree

Comment: This would probably be a bad idea in the middle of a rebase as it would pull the file from the head of that branch not at the detached head point you would be at in a conflicted rebase state

Comment: @Clintm, on the other hand it is a generic answer that you can pull the file from wherever you want. `branch1` would not be a particularly good idea as noted. But one can use a desired commit id.