# Overwrite a specific conflicting file in git with latest version

Tags: git

I have a few commits with several files in my local repository (not pushed yet). When I am doing a git pull in (EGit) it is showing many incoming changes and one file in conflict. I just want to replace this file with incoming changes but do not want other changes in my commits to be replaced. Just a single conflicting file replace. I tried `git checkout --theirs filename` from git bash followed by `git pull` resulting in the following message- `Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result` which is clear but I want to overwrite that conflict with latest one. How can I resolve this?

I don't know is this can be done without a rebase. A similar situation is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146289/how-to-get-their-changes-in-the-middle-of-conflicting-git-rebase) but that involves a rebase, which I want to avoid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8146289/how-to-get-their-changes-in-the-middle-of-conflicting-git-rebase

Comment: I don't want to do a rebase actually, the only thing I want is to replace the conflict from the latest version in the master.  So I don't think it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

> I tried git checkout --theirs filename from git bash followed by git
>   pull resulting in the following message- Automatic merge failed; fix
>   conflicts and then commit the result which is clear but I want to
>   overwrite that conflict with latest one. How can I resolve this?

You should do this:

1. git checkout --theirs filename # you get theirs changes
2. git add filename # add this file to stage
3. git commit -m 'resolve conflicts during merging, get theirs' # commit changes
4. git push # push your branch

Comment: Thanks, but unfortunately that doesn't work for me. The moment I commit it, a pull request doesn't fetch the latest changes for some reason, maybe I am missing some git concepts here.