# How to automatically always ignore compiled build folders during git rebase?

Tags: git, webpack, sass

I'm using git for a Laravel project that uses Webpack to minify javascript files and SCSS to generate CSS files.

I have a `master` branch and a `ws` branch.

When I'm in the `ws` branch and want to run `git rebase master`, I'm currently seeing 54 steps of conflicts.

Almost all of them are ones relating to the `public/js` or `public/css` directories or `composer.lock` or `public/mix-manifest.json`.

During my rebase, I don't want to spend any time manually resolving each of those conflicts because I plan to run `npm run production` afterwards anyway (which will regenerate `public/mix-manifest.json` and all the files in `public/js`) and take care of the SCSS and composer too.

I've read about [git rerere](https://hackernoon.com/fix-conflicts-only-once-with-git-rerere-7d116b2cec67) but get the sense that it is not helpful here.

I also don't want to manually run [git checkout --ours](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13621563/470749) dozens of times.

How can I make my rebase process faster and easier?

P.S. I wonder if [Choose Git merge strategy for specific files ("ours", "mine", "theirs")](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16825849/470749) is related.

Comment: So these files are the output of your build?  Can you just .gitignore them?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I'm using deployhq.com to deploy straight from my git repo, which is why I haven't used .gitignore on those folders.

Comment: That sounds like the crux of your problem.  I don't know anything about DeployHQ, but is it really the case that it can't orchestrate build steps as part of a deploy?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth I think that will be an option (although I think they'll charge for it monthly), so I'll consider it if I can't figure out something else. I'd rather not mess with my deployment process unless absolutely necessary. Thanks.

Comment: Oliver's suggestion is sound. Fix the root problem rather than deal with the accidental complexity it generates.

Comment: @Jubobs I agree with the principle that addressing a root cause is better than surface-level solutions. What I'm not clear on yet is why you're saying git shouldn't contain files generated by a build. What is the principle or best practice that I should be following?

Comment: @Ryan As a rule of thumb, no file that can be generated from source should be under version control. You should use a tool other than Git to handle (build, deploy, etc.) artifacts. Like Oliver, I'm not familiar with DeployHQ, but a cursory search reveals that it can build stuff as part of the deployment: https://www.deployhq.com/support/build-commands Look into that.

Comment: I agree that you should rather not have them in git at all. But as a side note, `git checkout` can glob like any other cli tool. So you can do `git checkout --ours public/*`